# Change DomainSID on Samba 4 PDC

Tags: domain, domain-controller, samba4

I've had trouble changing the Domain SID of my SAMBA 4 Domain Controller to an old one.
Let's say S-1-5-21-3307158569-4287292154-27117666 is the SID I want to set.
I use the following command:

```
net setdomainsid S-1-5-21-3307158569-4287292154-27117666
```

However this does not change. I have tried stopping all services and changing the SID but still no change unfortunately.
I still getting the old SID:

```
root@dc1:/var/lib/samba# net getdomainsid
SID for domain COMPANY is: S-1-5-21-3307158569-4287292154-27117854
```

I've also tried moving the secrets.tbd file but this did not resolve the issue either.

Could you help me out changing the domainSID to the one I want.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

- Stop Samba
- Backup and delete secrets.tdb
- Instead of `net setdomainsid` use `net setlocalsid`.
- Check result with `net getdomainsid`
- Start Samba

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but net setlocalid only changes the server SID if I understand correctly. it won't change the SID for the domain?

Comment: I did as you suggested. The domainSID did not change however. Only the LocalSID changed.

Comment: I see you're running the samba-ad-dc service. That one is only appropriate for AD style DCs. In your title, you mentioned a PDC which is an NT style DC (and you need to start smbd, nmbd and winbindd, instead of samba-ad-dc). For a PDC, localsid is equal to domainsid. For an AD DC, you are doing something wrong if you're manually trying to change the SID.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.
I'm new to all of this. I'm in fact trying to replicate a Windows 2012 Domain Controller which is a PDC for the domain "company.local". I am trying to manage all of this through a linux Domain Controller including pushing out Group Policies.

Comment: Can you tell me in which situation using ['net setdomainsid'] is appropriate?